# localstorage.removeItem with same looking code but one successfully removes the item while other not

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, local-storage

I have trouble understanding why exact looking code yield different result.

```
localStorage.removeItem('{"item":"Avocado Sandwich","option":"none","request":"dddsssaa"}');
localStorage.removeItem('{"Item":"Avocado Sandwich","option":"none","request":"dddsssaa"}');
```

They look exactly same right? but only the bottom one really removed from local.storage.

I got the first key from php using json_encode.

```
$removeitem = json_encode($array);


<input type="button" value="x" class="removeview" id="<?php echo $removeitem; ?>
```

I used jquery to remove the localstorage item.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.removeview').click(function(){
var item = $(this).attr('id');
localStorage.removeItem(item);
});
});
```

However, the code did not worked. Guessing something is wrong with the key, I used alert(item) to copy the item. Which was

```
{"item":"Avocado Sandwich","option":"none","request":"dddsssaa"}
```

I copied that item and used

```
 localStorage.removeItem('{"item":"Avocado Sandwich","option":"none","request":"dddsssaa"}');
```

Nothing worked.

Strange thing was I copied the item directly from localstorage 
in developer mode and pasted it in place above. The key looks exactly the same.

```
localStorage.removeItem('{"Item":"Avocado Sandwich","option":"none","request":"dddsssaa"}');
```

This time, it worked and removed the item. I even used String(item) just in case, but no luck.

Can anyone tell me what could be causing this?

Also, what would be correct way to remove stringified json from localStorage?

Comment: They are not the same, one has a capital i for item, the other doesnt

Comment: Why is that the key??? I think you need to rethink how you are using localstorage. You should be using a key and the string would be the value. `localStorage.setItem("food", '{"item":"Avocado Sandwich"}')`

Comment: I was so stupid. Yes. that was the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not exactly the same though.

This one has a lower case "`item`"

```
localStorage.removeItem('{"item":"Avocado Sandwich","option":"none","request":"dddsssaa"}');
```

This one has an uppercase "`Item`":

```
localStorage.removeItem('{"Item":"Avocado Sandwich","option":"none","request":"dddsssaa"}');
```